# c# String formatting an Integer to a Decimal

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I need help on C# string formatting an integer to a decimal. I cannot find a way to do this.
How can I convert an integer number like "45099" to a decimal like "450.99"?
Txs in adv
Ariel

Comment: Can you explain what a numeric type conversion combined with a division by 100 has to do with string formatting? By _"an integer number like '45099'"_, do you mean an `int` with a value of `45099`, or do you mean a `string` with the value `"45099"`? Same question for the decimal.

Comment: (value / 100m).ToString("N2")

Comment: Check this...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString

Comment: Sorry @stakx I forgot to mention that the final value will be sent as a json response, that was the reason why I thought on a string format solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 decimal d = (decimal)45099 / 100;
```